# Ambiguous use of "subscript"

Tags: swift

I'm having an issue trying to access the nth element of a Range using subscripts. The code is super simple:

```
var range = 0..<9
var itemInRange = range[n] // n is some Int where 0 <= n < 9
```

The second line complains with the error `Ambiguous use of "subscript"`, which I took to mean that Xcode wasn't clear what the type of the variable `range` is, and so it's unable to know which implementation of `subscript` to use. I tried to fix this by explicitly defining the type of `range` with

```
var range: Range<Int> = 0..<9
```

and

```
var firstInRange = (range as Range<Int>)[0]
```

but neither of these solved the problem. Is there a way to get Xcode to disambiguate the call to `subscript`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array with the range and then pick an element from the array.

```
var range = [Int](0..<9)
var itemInRange = range[1]
```

From apple docs

> A collection of consecutive discrete index values.
>
> Like other collections, a range containing one element has an endIndex
>   that is the successor of its startIndex; and an empty range has
>   startIndex == endIndex.
>
> Axiom: for any Range r, r[i] == i.
>
> Therefore, if Element has a maximal value, it can serve as an
>   endIndex, but can never be contained in a Range.
>
> It also follows from the axiom above that (-99..<100)[0] == 0. To
>   prevent confusion (because some expect the result to be -99), in a
>   context where Element is known to be an integer type, subscripting
>   with Element is a compile-time error:
>
> // error: could not find an overload for 'subscript'...
>
> print(Range(start: -99, end: 100)[0])

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Range_Structure/index.html

Comment: Your suggested code works just fine, but I'm totally confused by the axiom that you posted in support. Can you show me the source of that? It doesn't make any sense to me that the 0th element of a range that does not begin at zero is zero.

Comment: Sorry. I should have included the link.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Range_Structure/index.html

Comment: So it's just not possible to use subscripts on `Range` at all? I guess that makes sense given the reasoning that Apple gives, but it seems so contrived and immediately disprovable that it doesn't make any sense. Is there some weird computer science-y reason for the axiom they cite?

Comment: There might be but then it's beyond me.